# "This is the tent I had when I was a little boy." VS "This is the tent I have had since I was a little boy."

Tags: grammar, expressions, present-tense

Daddy Pig says:"This is the tent I had when I was a little boy." If he said :"This is the tent I have had since I was a little boy". Are there any subtle differences between the two expressions?
[image: context]

[text](https://peppapig.fandom.com/wiki/Camping/Transcript)

Comment: If it was said like "this is the tent I have had since I was a little boy" (or perhaps "this is the tent I have owned since I was a little boy", to remove the repeated use of "have") would it make sense to your understanding of tenses? To say "I have when I was" is creating a disagreement between the present "have" (with no statement about when the start was) and past "when I was" (with a defined start). To say "have had since" describes a past start to something that is still happening

Comment: It's probably a child's tent: a small one, for playing in. When he was a boy, Daddy pig might have called it *his* tent. In my house there is a doll that was my daughter's when she was young. Even if it's in my hand I still call it hers, not mine.

Comment: "This is the tent I've had since I was a little boy" as Caius says. Or "This was my tent when I was a little boy" (the latter a special logic-challenging usage used just in this sort of situation, meaning 'It's still my property, but I don't still regard it as my plaything, and [probably] I'd really like to see someone else play in it'. As Old Brixtonian implies.

Comment: @Caius Jard In the context if "this is the tent I have had since I was a little boy" would be proper?

Comment: That he had it then doesn't mean he doesn't still have it. I'm surprised this question hasn't been shuttled to ELL already.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth _"This is the tent I had when I was a little boy"_ .the part_ "I had"_makes me think   that Daddy Pig used to have the tent, but right now he doesn't. By the way I heard a song named "Marry had a little lamb". Can it means Marry used to have a little lamb, but right now she doesn't have.

Comment: "have/had" can mean something more than mere ownership: it can donate a particular relationship, or be used in an existential way ("I had a place I used to go to" doesn't mean a place I literally owned, but that there was a place that I used to go to regularly; similarly if a child says "I had a book I loved to read" they may not mean they owned it, but that it was in the house or just that they had access to it. Likewise "I had a song I liked to sing.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*When I was a little boy* is a period which is wholly in the past, so it requires a past-tense verb.

If it were *since I was a little boy*, that is a period which continues to the present, and so a non-past verb is appropriate.

Comment: uv, of course. I often wonder why answers like these don't receive all the upvotes. People go on and on about very little. I also wonder why those such as yourself do not step in on other questions that are similarly obvious and help to stop the flow of useless comments. Did you see exercise as in: Swimming is a good exercise? I tried my best but it was nigh impossible....Of course, the man is no longer a little boy.